# Bootstrap hover effect not working as expected in IE 11

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

Below is my `div` structure. I'm trying to create mega menu. like when user hover on`button` inside `dropdown` class the menu will appear with `slideDown`/`slideUp` effect. but initially it was not working even in chrome and behave like, menu started slidingDown/up when hover on any places in `dropdown` div,

i.e the hover effect applied on whole div instead of on hovering on button. so i used `display:contents` property for chrome and got fixed, but the same fix is not working for IE 11 because `display:contents` is not supported in IE 11.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">
            <span class="btn">Hover to see menu</span>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <!-- for responsive bootstrap grid combination will here -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-lg-2"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-lg-2"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-lg-2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

to be precise and clear, i want apply hover effect and show menu slidingUP/down only when user do hover inside the div contents not anywhere on entire div. spend nearly 3 days on this but no luck.

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: I suggest you post a code example with your CSS, JS code. so that we can try to run and check the issue. We are not able to produce the issue with your above HTML code. It is not working even with chrome. As you already know display: contents is not supported in IE and I did not get any alternative for the IE browser. As an alternative for Bootstrap Mega dropdown, you can refer to this example. It is working with the IE browser. Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_mega_menu.asp